# SSIS Script Transformation in Visual Studio - How to set the output fields

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ssis-2012

I'm trying to take data from two different sources, join them together, then with script transformation consolidate and average the data before exporting. So essentially, I have data that has date, duration, skill, and I want to consolidate it so that for each skill and date I have the average duration.
I have vba code in Input0_ProcessInputRow that sums everything up but I do not know how to do the math out and assign to the output after this.
Do I put it into the PostExecute()? If so, how do I create the rows for the output if the output fields are all different from the input.

Comment: Have you defined your output columns?

Comment: Are you using VBA, or VB.NET ?

Comment: @TimWilliams good catch. it's SSIS, so VB.NET

Comment: script language is Microsoft Visual Basic 2012 in properties.

Comment: Yes, and that is **not** VBA. It's VB.NET

Comment: I have output columns in the script transformation editor under Inputs and Columns. Do I need to define them in the script as well?

Comment: @Mat's Mug - thanks, I didnt know it was vb.net. I'm super new to all of this.